# Supersearch form escapes brackets

Tags: solspace, supersearch

I'm trying to filter using supersearch and checkboxes. Multiple checked checkboxes should create a get parameter like &myfield=value1&&value2. However, when I submit the form it escapes characters and fails to work.

Here's the bit of code with the checkboxes. It's a bigger form, but isolating this block won't work either:

```
<form method="get" action="/destinations/search">
    {exp:super_search:search}
    <fieldset class="amenities">
        <h3>Filter by feature</h3>
        {exp:low_options:amenities}
        {options}
        <span>
            <input type="checkbox" name="amenities[]" value="{option:value}">
            <label>{option:label}</label>
        </span>
        {/options}
        {/exp:low_options:amenities}
    </fieldset>
    <input type="submit" class="update" value="Update results">
    {/exp:super_search:search}</form>
```

The resulting url gives something like: 
?amenities%5B%5D=barbecue&amenities%5B%5D=car-essentials

In the example I'm using low_options but I've also tried simply coding the fields.
Am I missing something obvious? This is the last piece of a big project and has me scratching my head over and over.

Thanks in advance!!

Best,
Santiago.-

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Super Search works best as a **POST** form. **GET** forms are more limited. As mentioned in the docs (http://www.solspace.com/docs/super_search/post_get_or_template/):

> GET does have it's limitations. As mentioned above, it is impossible to pass search arrays via GET.

Try using `method="post"` instead for your form.

Comment: That solves it. I'm still trying to figure out of a way to chain the values this way: value1&&value2 instead of value1+value2, but I guess that's for another question.

Comment: Try adding `&&` after each of your checkbox values. Eg. `value="toothbrush&&"`